# Getting references of frames as a png

Tags: texturing

I am currently following the tutorial of Peter France on YouTube for a head explosion. In his video he has all the frames saved in a folder as a png. I wonder how he did that. Can somebody help me?

In the picture below you can see his references[image]

Comment: In shotcut, for example, you can load the clip into the timeline and export, not as an mp4 but as a png series.  You just designate a folder.

Comment: I think you could do the same in Blender, just open in the video editing preset, load the clip and export to a folder as png

Comment: Speaking to the close vote: i think the linked question is slightly different, this user wants to take reference footage, not the blender render, and export as a png sequence

Comment: @AllenSimpson correct

Comment: @AllenSimpson i will try the shotcut thing